# Rails :less_than validation makes RSpec test fail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, validation, rspec

Using:

- Ruby 2.6.6
- Rails 6.0.2.2

I have a Model, `Part`, which has 2 fields, `quantity_available` and `minimum_order`.

I have the following validations to make sure that:

- `minimum_order` and `quantity_available` must exist
- `minimum_order` and `quantity_available` cannot be 0 or negative
- `minimum_order` cannot be a higher value than `quantity_available`

```rb
class Part < ApplicationRecord
  validates :quantity_available, :minimum_order, presence: true
  validates_numericality_of :quantity_available, :minimum_order, only_integer: true, greater_than: 0
  validates_numericality_of :minimum_order, only_integer: true, less_than: :quantity_available
end
```

The validation works fine when I test it manually using `rails console` to create a new Part that clashes with the above validations, however one of my RSpec tests is failing

```rb
# RSpec
RSpec.describe Part, type: :model do
  let(:part) { Part.new(quantity_available: 250, minimum_order: 10)} 

  it 'is not valid without a Quantity Available' do
    part.quantity_available = nil
    expect(part).to_not be_valid
  end
end
```

```sh
# Console Error
Failures:

  1) Part basic checks is not valid without a Quantity Available
     Failure/Error: expect(part).to_not be_valid

     TypeError:
       cant convert nil into Float
     # ./spec/models/part_spec.rb:32:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

As you can see it's a very simple test that simply states that a Part that has no `quantity_available` should fail, however in this case it technically does fail, just not in the fashion that I want it to be failing.

My best guess is that it probably has something to do with declaring the `quantity_available` as `nil` in the test causing a crossing of wires somewhere as it can't validate all 3 conditions. I have a test for `minimum_order` that is identical to the one above, yet that one passes as expected.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: might be because `only_integer` expects it to be an integer and `nil` is not an integer. it's doing this under the hood. you could do an `expect raise_error` though.

Comment: I didn't think about the `only_integer` bit, but that makes sense.

Removed that, but the same was still happening, so for now I just converted the test into `expect { part.save }.to raise_error TypeError`, and it'll do for now. Cheers!

Comment: Are you confident that it is expected behaviour? I think it's workaround.

Comment: @AmitPatel You're right, it did feel like a workaround that was ignoring the issue. See my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I might have reached a good solution that isn't just a workaround that doesn't actually solve the original issue I was having with the test.

Running the following while in `rails c` throws a validation error, as expected:

```rb
new = Part.create(available_quantity: 0, minimum_order: 10)
new.save # => false
new.errors.full_messages # => ["Quantity available must be greater than 0", "Minimum order must be less than or equal to 0"]
```

As you can see, the 2 validations work exactly as expected, but the issue in the test is that one validation is actually getting in the way of the other, which obviously causes issues with the passing of the test.

At this point, there are two options that I saw in order to proceed:

1. **Make this one specific test also have a nil value for the `minimum_order` field.**

This causes some minor code repetition and just overall wasn't good enough for my tastes

2. **Simply skip the validation if the current value of the `quantity_available` field is nil or 0.**

This one makes a lot more sense. After all, the 1st validation is going to make sure a 0 never makes it into the DB for either of these fields, so it's safe to simply skip the 2nd validation if a 0 or nil *is* present. If it's not, the validation will fire and only then will it compare the two values.

The solution, then, is pretty simple; Just stick an `unless:` into the validation that evaluates a lambda

```rb
validates_numericality_of :minimum_order, less_than: :quantity_available, unless: -> { quantity_available.nil? || quantity_available == 0 }
```

With that, all Tests are green, no workarounds were needed, and I'm pretty sure my Model is the tiniest bit more efficient in its validation checks

Answer (score 1):

I guess the symbol is not really evaluated to the field value, try 
passing a lambda like this:

```rb
validates_numericality_of :minimum_order, 
                          only_integer: true, 
                          less_than: -> { quantity_available }
```